# Centering a linked button with the HREF only in the button

Tags: html, css

I have a link in a centered button but the problem is that the link is clickable in all of the x axis in the button. I just want the link to be in the button image. **An easier way to explain is that the the pointer cursor turns into a hand cursor if it is beside the button. I just want it to turn into a hand cursor if it is on the button. Here is my code.**

```css
img.center2 {
    display: block;
    margin-top: 28px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
```

```html
<a href="SignUp.html"><img src="Button1.png" class="center2"></a>
```

Answer (score 1):

It's because your button is a block level element, you need to make it inline-block

```css
img.center2 {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-top: 28px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}

div.container {
    text-align: center
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <a href="SignUp.html"><img src="Button1.png" class="center2"></a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
Curosor: hand;
```

This should make the cursor a hand when it goes over the image.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way you can put the image inside a "button" made with a div element.

I painted the background red for it to be evident. You can customize it the way you need.

```css
.btnContainer{
    width:50px;
    height: 30px;
    padding: 15px 20px;
    background: red;
    text-align:center;
}
.btnContainer a{
    display:inline-block;
    margin:0 auto;    
}
```

```html
<div class="btnContainer">
<a href="SignUp.html"><img src="Button1.png" class="center2"></a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.center img {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-top: 28px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}

.center {
    text-align: center
}
```

```html
<div class="center">
    <a href="SignUp.html"><img src="Button1.png"></a>
</div>
```